# UIView animations: the "beginAnimations:context" method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm doing a lot of animations in my app, and I was wondering whether passing `nil` as the `context` parameter to `[UIView beginAnimations:context]` is ok to do.

When would I want to pass anything in as the `context` param and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the same delegate for several animations, you can use the context to distinguish between them.  If you have some temporary value that you want to pass to your delegate, pass it in context.  If none of the above then pass nil.